# Layout folder name for tablet 21"

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I have a tablet of 21" (hp slate) and I would like to create folder layout to suit my views on this type of screens, I wonder what name to choose for my folder: layout-xxxxdp!

Answer (score 1):

Given the screen [dimensions and resolution](http://www.phonearena.com/news/HP-Slate-21-is-a-21.5-Android-tablet-all-in-one-powered-by-Tegra-4_id44428), the screen's DPI is **105**.

That would make it a `xlarge`+ screen but only `ldpi`.

You can use `layout-xlarge-ldpi` to target it.

**EDIT**

Applying the `dp = px / (ppi / 160dp)` formula, we can even use `layout-sw2925dp` I believe, because I calculated dp=2925 (I might be wrong, please correct me).

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I added my layouts in layout-xlarge-ldpi folder but i don't have what i wanted :(!

Comment: Works with `layout-xlarge`? Works with `layout-sw2925dp`?

Comment: I tried with layout-sw1080dp-land, and it works lovely ;) thankyou shkschneider

Comment: Glad it helped. Remember to put qualifiers in order of appearance in "Table 2" of https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html ;)